# How to change the format in docker logs

Tags: docker, logging, docker-compose

I have this logging output.
I want to have a different format for the time.
I want only time (no date, and no timezone)

```
Container PW-Backend                  Created                                        0.0s
Attaching to PW-Backend
PW-Backend  | [2023-07-21 09:24:45 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
PW-Backend  | [2023-07-21 09:24:45 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (1)
PW-Backend  | [2023-07-21 09:24:45 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: sync
PW-Backend  | [2023-07-21 09:24:45 +0000] [7] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7
```

I just cant find the documentation for specifying the the format of the logging output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logging format of the application is not docker related. Docker will just log the output from the main process via specified logging driver which by default is the json-file driver. It doesn't mean that your logs will be in json format, it means that the file on the host that the logs are stored in is in json format.

example record:

```
{"log":"Hello World!\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2020-03-29T22:51:31.549390877Z"}
```

In your case I would first check if I can change the log format in the application and if not use some log processing tool to make it in the correct format that I want and ship it to some logging backend. ie: Logstash to Elasticsearch

Comment: Ah, yeah I realize now that the that time format is logged by the application inside docker. 
thank you for the answer